# How to delete mail items using office 365 REST API in provided powershell script sample

Tags: api, rest, email, powershell, office365

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem for quite a while now and nothing I've found seems to work. I am hoping to use this script:

```
##-----------------------------------------------------## 
##        PICK AUTH Method                             ## 
##-----------------------------------------------------## 

## HARD CODING PSW    ## 
#$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxx" -AsPlainText -Force 
#$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "xxx@xxx.onmicrosofot.com",$password 

## USER PROMPT PSW    ## 
#$cred = Get-Credential 

##-----------------------------------------------------## 
##    END PICK 
##-----------------------------------------------------## 

$url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages" 
$date = "2014-11-21" 

## Get all messages that have attachments where received date is greater than $date  
$messageQuery = "" + $url + "?`$select=Id&`$filter=HasAttachments eq true and DateTimeReceived ge " + $date 
$messages = Invoke-RestMethod $messageQuery -Credential $cred 

## Loop through each results 
foreach ($message in $messages.value) 
{ 
    # get attachments and save to file system 
    $query = $url + "/" + $message.Id + "/attachments" 
    $attachments = Invoke-RestMethod $query -Credential $cred 

    # in case of multiple attachments in email 
    foreach ($attachment in $attachments.value) 
    { 
        $attachment.Name 
        $path = "c:\Temp\" + $attachment.Name 

        $Content = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($attachment.ContentBytes) 
        Set-Content -Path $path -Value $Content -Encoding Byte 
    } 
}
```

That I found from link - [TechNet Office 365 Scripts](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/O365-Email-Attachments-to-6a45e84c#content)

I can get the script to work fine, it connects to mailbox and downloads the attachments for emails specified after the date variable. Problem is that I would like to run this on an hourly schedule and delete previously processed emails so that their attachments are not stripped on consecutive runs.

I've tried lots of different commands to delete the email with no success and also tried altering the $messageQuery to include only items within a specific date range but can't get anything working.

Can anyone provide the correct syntax for the delete command in powershell and an example of how to use it in this context please?

Thanks

Rich

---

UPDATE - I think adding in:

```
$query2 = $url + "/" + $message.Id
```

And

```
Invoke-RestMethod $query2 -Credential $cred -Method Delete
```

Is getting me closer but I now get operation timed out.

---

UPDATE - Full code as it stands and as requested:

```
##-----------------------------------------------------## 
##        PICK AUTH Method                             ## 
##-----------------------------------------------------## 

## HARD CODING PSW    ## 
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force 
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "email@address.co.uk",$password 

## USER PROMPT PSW    ## 
##$cred = Get-Credential 

##-----------------------------------------------------## 
##    END PICK 
##-----------------------------------------------------## 

#$url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages" 
$url = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/ODATA/me/messages"
$today = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd 
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")


## Set date and query  
$messageQuery = "" + $url + "?`$select=Id&`$filter=HasAttachments eq true and DateTimeReceived lt " + $today #+ " and DateTimeReceived gt" + $date
$messages = Invoke-RestMethod $messageQuery -Credential $cred 

## Loop through each results 
foreach ($message in $messages.value) 
{ 
    # get attachments and save to file system 
    $query = $url + "/" + $message.Id + "/attachments" 
    $query2 = $url + "/" + $message.Id
    $attachments = Invoke-RestMethod $query -Credential $cred 

    # in case of multiple attachments in email 
    foreach ($attachment in $attachments.value) 
    { 
        $attachment.Name 
        $path = "\\SomePath\" + $attachment.Name 

        $Content = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($attachment.ContentBytes) 
        Set-Content -Path $path -Value $Content -Encoding Byte 

    } 

    Invoke-RestMethod $query2 -Credential $cred -Method Delete -TimeoutSec 100   

} 

#Move pdf files to another folder
#Move-Item '\\SomePath\*.pdf' '\\SomePath'

#Then delete any existing files from directory
#Remove-Item '\\SomePath\*'
```

---

I tried to alter the date section to allow for a start and end date so the script could be run once a day, do the extraction but not reprocess attachments from previous days but ran into issues working out the syntax to alter the $messageQuery.

Response from running the script  is:

Invoke-RestMethod : The operation has timed out.
At C:\Scripts\EmailExtractServiceContract365.ps1:26 char:13
+ $messages = Invoke-RestMethod $messageQuery -Credential $cred
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: Can you show your full delete code? Can you capture the request and post it here?

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your response, posted the code but unsure of how to capture the request? Could you point me in the right direction please? Cheers, Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not an answer**

Use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the request. Use the https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages endpoint. The other one has been deprecated (I think). Post your sanitized request/response here.

**Your script is probably not the problem**

I got the script to work fine; it finds an email with attachment, saves the attachment, then deletes the email. I'm not sure what is going on in your environment until I see the requests (remove the auth headers if you post the request). I only changed the $today value to capture emails with attachments today.

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force 
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "user@contoso.com",$password 

$url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages" 
$today = (Get-Date).AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

## Set date and query  
$messageQuery = "" + $url + "?`$select=Id&`$filter=HasAttachments eq true and DateTimeReceived lt " + $today #+ " and DateTimeReceived gt" + $date
$messages = Invoke-RestMethod $messageQuery -Credential $cred 

## Loop through each results 
foreach ($message in $messages.value) 
{ 
    # get attachments and save to file system 
    $query = $url + "/" + $message.Id + "/attachments" 
    $query2 = $url + "/" + $message.Id
    $attachments = Invoke-RestMethod $query -Credential $cred 

    # in case of multiple attachments in email 
    foreach ($attachment in $attachments.value) 
    { 
        $attachment.Name 
        $path = "C:\temp\" + $attachment.Name 

        $Content = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($attachment.ContentBytes) 
        Set-Content -Path $path -Value $Content -Encoding Byte 

    } 

    Invoke-RestMethod $query2 -Credential $cred -Method Delete -TimeoutSec 100   
}
```

**REQUEST**

Here's what the request and response should look like to delete the email.

```
DELETE https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkADBjYXXXXXXXXXX= HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; en-US) WindowsPowerShell/5.0.10586.0
Authorization: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Host: outlook.office365.com
Cookie: ClientId=CQA
Content-Length: 0
```

**RESPONSE**

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, got it working after you mentioned probably environment rather than script. Tried running it on a different machine, worked fine. Went back to the original and elevated the PowerShell ISE to run as admin and low and behold, working. Silly me. I guess the fact everything but the delete was working without elevation through me off. Thanks for your help.